# How can I add a <g> element to my chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm following a long Mike Bostocks' Let's make a Bar Chart tutorial and I'm stuck after I decided, that my bars need some text.

As far as I understood it, `rect` cannot contain `text` elements, so I need to create a grouping and wrap both, text and rect in it. The problem is, that my code refuses to render the groupings (and the bars for that matter).
In fact, it does not even execute the section to append a `<g>` element. If I throw in a console.log or alert into the callback it does never get called.

Full code for reference below. The part in question is:

```
var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
              .data(data)
            .enter().append("g")
              .attr("transform", function(d) {
                  return "translate(" + x(d.letter) + "," + y(d.value) + ")";
              });
```

Full code:

```
var margin = { top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 40 }, width = 960, height = 500;

var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x),
    yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y)
        .ticks(10, "%").tickPadding(11);

var chart = d3.select(".chart")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


d3.tsv("../data.tsv", type, function (err, data) {
    x.domain(data.map(function (d) {
        return d.letter;
    }));
    //set domain of scale, it is now known
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
        return d.value;
    })]);

    //append the xAis
    chart.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height) + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    chart.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", 6)
            .attr("dy", ".71em")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .text("Frequency");

    var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
          .data(data)
        .enter().append("g")
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
              return "translate(" + x(d.letter) + "," + y(d.value) + ")";
          });

    bar.append("rect")
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth());
});

function type(d) {
    //coerce property to be number -> 
    //find out what the difference between + and Number() is.
    d.value = +d.frequency;
    return d;
}
```

So, where did I go wrong and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems, the first one being a simple selection order and the second one being conceptual.

The first problem is this: when you write

```
 var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
```

for creating your groups, you're selecting groups that already exist in your SVG, which are the axes and an initial group added to the SVG.

So, select something else, something that doesn't exist:

```
var bar = chart.selectAll(".foo")
```

Your second problem is conceptual: although you're correct about being impossible to append a text to a rect, you *don't* need g elements to achieve what you want. Just create a rect selection and a text selection, and append both to the SVG.

But if you want to add the groups, this is what you have to do.

First, in the data binding, select something that doesn't exist:

```
var groups = chart.selectAll(".groups")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + x(d.letter) + ",0)";
    });
```

Translate only the x position of the groups, the y position of their elements will be set individually.

Then, create the bars:

```
var bar = groups.append("rect")
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.value);
    })
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", function(d) {
        return height - y(d.value);
    });
```

And finally your texts:

```
var text = groups.append("text")
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.value) - 6;
    })
    .attr("x", x.bandwidth() / 2)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.value
    });
```

This is a demo using your code and fake data:

```js
var data = d3.csvParse(d3.select("#csv").text());

data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.value = +d.value
});

var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 30,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 40
    },
    width = 960,
    height = 500;

var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    .padding(0.3);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x),
    yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y)
    .ticks(10, "%").tickPadding(11);

var chart = d3.select(".chart")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.letter;
}));
//set domain of scale, it is now known
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.value;
})]);

var groups = chart.selectAll(".groups")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + x(d.letter) + ",0)";
    })

var bar = groups.append("rect").attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.value);
    })
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", function(d) {
        return height - y(d.value);
    });

var text = groups.append("text")
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.value) - 6;
    })
    .attr("x", x.bandwidth() / 2)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.value
    });

//append the xAis
chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height) + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Frequency");
```

```css
pre {
 display: none;
}

rect {
 fill: teal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg class="chart"></svg>
<pre id="csv">letter,value
A,.08167
B,.01492
C,.02782
D,.04253
E,.12702
F,.02288
G,.02015</pre>
```

Comment: This pretty much solves my problem. Altough I now need to read up on `.selectAll()` and why I need to select an element that does not exist.

Comment: I wrote this in the documentation, maybe it can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/d3.js/2135/selections/16948/the-role-of-placeholders-in-enter-selections#t=201612210718238687186

Comment: I'm feeling a bit dimwitted right now. I totally forgot that "Documentations" actually exist here on SO. You deserve a beer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept that beer! It's a shame that, unfortunately, "Documentations" is almost dying (specially among low-popularity tags, like `d3.js`).